# Ruby on Rails - image_tag links not working in posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

trying to make link to my recent uploaded image

```
<%= link_to (image_tag (post.image_url(:thumb))), post.image.url(:original), :class => 'postimage' %>
```

how ever it's not working, at all...

```
   <% @post.image do |image| %>

   <%= link_to (image_tag (post.image_url(:thumb))), post.image.url(:original), :class        => 'postimage' %>

 <% end %>
```

the fun part is that

```
<%=  @post.image %>
```

works. but only shows /uploads/post/image/3/eKoh3.jpg

full code here https://gist.github.com/4332533

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Also please describe exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks wrong to me:

```
<% @post.image do |image| %>
```

(btw your gist actually says `@post.image.each do |image|`, which I'm assuming is what you meant to do above)

If you are mounting an uploader on your Post model's `:image` attribute, then this makes no sense. A mounted uploader allows you to upload one image, and you can't iterate over it using `each`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to iterate over all the versions? Try `post.image.versions.each`

Are you trying to upload multiple images? Carrierwave can't help you with that directly. You'll need to create a new model, `Image`, and mount your uploader there. Your `Post` will need a line like

```
has_many :images
```

And your `Image` model will need to `belong_to :post`. You'll also need to figure out how to upload and manage images in that new table.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is. added carrierwave to my posts. so when i write a post i can add images to the post. I got it working now how ever with this link                                                                     <%= link_to image_tag(@post.image_url(:thumb)), @post.image.url(:original), :class => 'postimage'%>     It shows the image. now i just a way to delete the image agian in my _forms.html.erb

Comment: @KennyBülowLarsen mounting a carrierwave uploader to your Post model will allow you to upload ONE image per post. If you upload another, it'll overwrite the existing one.

Comment: hmm might i ask a way to add multiple files ? in case you know how then ? or shall i submit a new question ? i was thinking about use the jquery for added more fields

Comment: @KennyVB You should submit a new question for that :)